# Compare dates in Visual Basic

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, date

I want to compare the current date with dates that I have saved in my database. When the date on the database has passed 30 days from the current date, I want to display a message that the period has expired and the customer needs to pay the money. Below is my code

```
con = New SqlConnection
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\user\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;"

Dim READER As SqlDataReader
Dim date1 As Date

date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(Today)

Try
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        con.Open()

        COMMAND = New SqlCommand("SELECT distinct Surname,Money,Date from [Table] where money!=N'no'", con)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader

        While READER.Read()
            If date1 > READER(2).AddDays(30) Then
                MessageBox.Show("The customer N'" & TextBox1.Text & " has debts N'" & ComboBox3.SelectedItem)
            End If
        End While

        con.Close()
    Next

    con.Close()

Catch ex As SqlException
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
    con.Dispose()
End Try
```

Comment: What is the problem? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55089941/edit) your question to tell us.

Comment: It doesn't run correctly. There is a problem with the if statement.

Comment: `READER(2)` should be `READER.GetDateTime(2)`.

Comment: I changed it, but still it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are using unnecessarily `Convert.ToDateTime` to convert `Today` which is already a `Date` to a `Date`. On the other side `Reader(2)` returns an `Object` that you are not converting to a `Date`.

But why doing this comparison in VB? You are returning a potentially high number of records that you will have to discard. Do the comparison in SQL.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Surname, Money, Date
FROM [Table]
WHERE Money != N'no' AND Date < (GETDATE() - 30)
```

Comment: I tried it, but the date that it is displayed on the query is 1900-01-01

Comment: `1900-01-01` is older than 30 days. But difficult to say without seeing your actual data. Also, how are you displaying the date? I also assume that you have used a date type in SQL-Server and not a string type. See also [Date and Time Data Types and Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: I use for date the varchar type. I will try to change it and see if it works.

Comment: @PaulosXampos storing date as char is always a bad idea, and naming a column "date" too, because its a reserved word.